# How do I enable http2 in C# Kestrel web server over plain http?

Tags: c#, http

How do I (and is it possible) to enable http2 over plain http in the C# Kestrel web server? All Microsoft documentation indicates that https/TLS is required, but I have services that will be running behind a load-balancer or nginx and as such don't need a second layer of https. The official http2 spec indicates that https is not required.

Comment: What are you seeing currently? I haven't played with *just* http2, but I've played with gRPC over non-TLS http2, and it "just worked" : https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/master/examples/dotnet-grpc/DN_Server/Program.cs ; note: HttpClient is the fussy one! You need to enable a feature flag to get the client API to connect over non-TLS http2 (https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/master/examples/dotnet-grpc/DN_Client/Program.cs#L15)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I am using httpclient and that was one of my issues, so that link is helpful. I'm using Kestrel web server with controllers that return JSON. Maybe unencrypted http2 is not possible in this scenario and I will need to bypass Kestrel and go to a raw gRPC style socket, if so I'm fine with that.

Comment: again: what are you actually seeing?

Comment: Ok, the appstate thing seems to be part of the equation. But I am hoping to let http2 be enabled using the configuration urls, rather than hard-coding to localhost and a port. Is this possible at all? Setting the appstate flag only doesn't get me http2, still uses 1.x. So I assume I need to enable it somewhere in the kestrel options?

Comment: I did nothing special and I've HTTP2 when the server is running on Win10. However, I noticed that the same app moved onto Linux is not able to manage HTTP2. A colleague told me that is a Linux problem, and you should enable HTTP2 at the OS level.

Comment: awesome; nice job

Comment: @MarioVernari are you running behind nginx or something else on Linux? Or exposed directly?

Comment: @jjxtra directly, at the moment.

Comment: Hmmm. Seems weird. I am at least able to get http2 working fine in a docker container for Linux. This is .net core 3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unencrypted http2 can be necessary for load balancers, proxies, etc.

You must do three things to use http2 over unencrypted channel.

**Setup Kestrel to use http2 on your server:**

```
builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults((webBuilder) =>
{
    // this will keep your other end points settings such as --urls parameter
    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((options) =>
    {
        // trying to use Http1AndHttp2 causes http2 connections to fail with invalid protocol error
        // according to Microsoft dual http version mode not supported in unencrypted scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.0
        options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(lo => lo.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
    });
});
```

**For .net 5+, create your `HttpClient` instance, then create a message and specify the version:**

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
{
    Version = HttpVersion.Version20,
    VersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrHigher
};
```

**For .net core 3.1 and older, set a flag to enable http2 unencrypted. Then, when you create an `HttpClient`, specify the version:**

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl), DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0) };
```

If you need to support both http1 and http2 on a completely unencrypted host, then you will need to listen on two ports, one for each http version. Then your load balancer or proxy would need to handle the http version and direct to the appropriate port.

You won't see http2 on your browser and will likely get a protocol error, so in those cases you can use an http1 protocol directive just for development environment. Not ideal, but it at least lets you test locally.

Comment: Only clients need to set `Http2UnencryptedSupport` flag. You can also set `Http2` via `appsettings.json` but still have problem for those calls from browser!

Comment: Thanks for the mention of `HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrHigher`!

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost` instead of the generic `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host` for the `CreateDefaultBuilder` as you will run into an annoying `OpenSslCryptographicException` when running dotnet core 3 grpc containers on docker linux instances.

Also, if you are using health checks, be sure to expose it on a different port as illustrated in the below `Program.cs` snippet:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureKestrel(options => {
            //grpc port for http2 connections
            options.ListenAnyIP(xxxx, listenOptions => {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });
            //add health check on a separate port instead of Http1AndHttp2 on same port
            options.ListenAnyIP(xxxx, listenOptions => {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
            });
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use configuration section for Kestrel in appSettings.json.

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  },
```

To turn of SSL, you may want to remove `app.UseHsts()`, `app.UseHttpsRedirections()` options from Statup.cs Configure method and expose only Http url.

You can also use `Http1AndHttp2` to support both `Http1` and `Http2` together.

Comment: This setting can also be adjusted by an environment variable `Kestrel__EndpointDefaults__Protocols=Http2`.  That makes it easy to add to `launchSettings.json`

Answer (score 2):

In dotnet 5 `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);` is no longer supported.

To allow prior knowledge http/2 you need to configure your HttpRequestMessage:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://localhost/something"))
            {
                Version = HttpVersion.Version20,
                VersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrHigher //This allows http/2 unencrypted,
            };
```

For reference: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/987

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question here is more about how to configure the web server than the client, but this is still helpful.

Comment: The best answer for dotnet 5