# How to enable HTTP2 in Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

IIS is not involved. Everything is running on local computer, Windows 10 x64. Tried creating different kinds of projects, like Blazor and Web API, the result is on the screenshot - invalid response, although in IE 11 it shows some weird characters. Chrome and MS Edge don't even try to display the page.

In the code below I tried different combinations of protocols, on the same port and IP or different ones. Only endpoints using `HTTP1` work fine. Suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682933/how-do-i-enable-http2-in-c-sharp-kestrel-web-server-over-plain-http) didn't help.

How do I enable HTTP2 in Kestrel?

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
  var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

  var environment = WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseConfiguration(configuration)
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    //.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001")
    .UseStaticWebAssets()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
      //options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 0, o =>
      {
        //o.UseHttps("Certificate.pfx", "Demo");
        o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
      });

      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 0, o =>
      {
        o.UseHttps("Certificate.pfx", "Demo");
        o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
      });
    });

  return environment;
}
```

[image: IE 11 vs MS Edge]

Comment: If you do nothing, HTTPS is enabled by default and the HTTPS endpoint uses the developer certificate.

Comment: @davidfowl HTTPS works fine in any case if protocol is HTTP1. The question is, which settings I need to tweak to enable HTTP2 protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https` is required for `http2`
This works fine for `net5.0` (checked in Chrome with protocol column enabled)

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000, o =>
                {
                    o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2; // with this line or not - both works fine
                    o.UseHttps();
                });
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

As per the docs

> Starting with .NET Core 3.0, HTTP/2 is enabled by default

[Use HTTP/2 with the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/http2?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Tried to replace basic Blazor template in VS with your code, the result is the same. Blank page in a browser with invalid response. Maybe HTTP2 requires activating some Windows feature?

Comment: In my local Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 VPS HTTPS works fine, only HTTP2 is not available. In Windows 11 of another person, both HTTPS and HTTP2 are unavailable.

Comment: Can you share the project? I can check at my local

Comment: https://github.com/artemiusgreat/Http2AspCore - this demo creates 2 servers, HTTP1 and HTTP2, but HTTP2 returns `Invalid Response`

Comment: Your sample works fine for me If I add `o.UseHttps();` for HTTP2