# Postman - "Could not load server reflection. Details: unknown error" when using GRPC server reflection

Tags: c#, postman, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to use Postman on my GRPC service as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/test-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Unfortunately, I am getting the error below:

> Could not load server reflection.
> Details: unknown error

[image]

In Console I can see a bunch of info messages, no errors:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682933/how-do-i-enable-http2-in-c-sharp-kestrel-web-server-over-plain-http)
> Request finished HTTP/2 POST http://localhost:5001/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo
> application/grpc - - 200 - application/grpc 57.0449ms
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682933/how-do-i-enable-http2-in-c-sharp-kestrel-web-server-over-plain-http)
> Request finished HTTP/2 POST http://localhost:5001/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo
> application/grpc - - 200 - application/grpc 158.2632ms
> info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISSrO.png)
> Executed endpoint 'gRPC - /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo'

Not sure what can be done to investigate and fix.
**If I import the proto files to Postman, I can execute an endpoint and it works OK.**

Some details:

- I am using http/2 over HTTP.
- Postman Version 10.14.5
- All grpc packages are version 2.50.0
- I am tried a few ways of enabling http/2 as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682933/how-do-i-enable-http2-in-c-sharp-kestrel-web-server-over-plain-http)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The client and server must both support the mode being used for the connection.  HTTP has three modes 1) HTTP 1.0 2) HTTP 1.1 3) HTTP/2.  So first client and server need to support http/2.  Second server may be configured to only work with HTTPS (encrypted) and you are using non encrypted.  If a secure connection is being made Postman may be using OpenSSL to do encryption.  Postman is smarter than c# clients and may be doing things different than c#.

Comment: @jdweng - thanks - but given I can call the service from that very postman instance and get proper responses from the endpoints, I would say there's no protocol error...
It's just the service discovery that fails... Also, when I didn't have my service running on http2 I would get a different error (`protocol error` if I recall correctly...)

Comment: more precisely, when the service is not available on http/2, I do not see the attempted requests info and the error in postman is `Could not load server reflection.
Details: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error`

Comment: The error just indicates the connection did not complete or was closed.  Read following.  I think it has to do with STREAM mode : https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Have you tried using gRPCurl instead? The instructions you're using include [gRPCurl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/test-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0#grpcurl) instructions too. This would eliminate Postman as your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl instead of Postman to connect to the service. It immediately gave me meaningful error:

> Failed to resolve symbol "My.Service":
> Symbol not found: My.Service
> caused by: File not found: google/protobuf/Empty.proto

It was a bit puzzling, especially that the service works OK.
However, it turns out that my import definitions had an incorrect casing (see https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/issues/203).

I had `"google/protobuf/Empty.proto";` instead of `import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";`.

After correcting it works fine both in Postman and Grpcurl.

For the record - it's not that Grpcurl has **better** error handling than Postman.
It depends - for example, when an incorrect protocol is used (HTTP 1 instead of HTTP 2), Grpcurl just says `Failed to dial target host "localhost:5001": context deadline exceeded` whereas Postman's error is more meaningful: `INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error`